# Incompatible Hyper-V is running Gameloop

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v

I've seen someone post the same problem as me about Gameloop but they didn't get a clear answer and I cant understand most of them as well.

I have a Windows 11 Home edition and whenever I try to download something from the custom installation it will say

> incompatible hyper-v is running. Close hyper-v and start the game again.

I technically do not have a Hyper-V so I'm quite confused. I checked my Services as the video I found said, and somehow found Hyper-V in there. I don't know if those are the same but I stopped them.

However, that didn't work either. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question doesn't give any details about what you're trying to do. It would perhaps be simpler for you to give screenshots.

Comment: The Gameloop FAQs give instructions to [Turn off the Windows Hypervisor Platform](https://www.gameloop.com/blog/faqs/fix-incompatible-hyperv-detection). Have you tried that yet?

Comment: The other questions on this site note specific details about disabling HyperV correctly for this tool. While you say you had difficulty understanding them, can you explain what it is about those answers you do not understand?